# "Unresolved" error importing rxjs in Typescript application

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs

I'm building a nodejs app written in Typescript and I'm trying to import reactivex module version 5 which is also written in Typescript. Here is the [repository](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs).

I followed their guide via the Readme file and installed reactivejs by running the following command:

```
npm install rxjs-es
```

Now i have module A that im trying to import rxjs declarations by writing:

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

It looks like Webstorm can't find the module to import and produces an error:

> "cannot resolve directory 'rxjs'"

and it's right, there is no such directory, I've installed rxjs-es and I have a rxjs-es directory under node_modules.

I also tried to install using:

```
npm install @reactivex/rxjs
```

but it doesnt find 'rxjs' directory also with this approach.

Comment: Just use require. Seriously.

Comment: if im using 'require' instead of 'import' the auto completion with Webstorm isnt so good, i want to load libraries the Typescript way not Javascript way..

Comment: There is no native implementation of es6 modules. The typescript compiler converts it to a require/define/global-variable-lookup depending on the environment. There is no such thing as 'the Typescript way'. You can specify the correct path using `import`, or you can just use `require('rxjs')` and the node registry will find it for you.

Comment: so when im writing import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'; it tries to find it relatively to where module A is located? tsc shouldnt also search in node_modules directory?